# Nodemailer Not Working With Heroku Deployment

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, nodemailer

Long story short, I wanted to add a email system to my application so I decided on Nodemailer. Everything works fine on localhost but once I try to send an email from my heroku deployed site, it fails with a `500` internal error.

I've already done the stuff with my gmail account to allow it to accept unsecure apps and stuff.

Here is my nodemailer setup:

```
app.post('/sendMail', (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, total } = req.body
  const nameCheck = name
    .split(' ')
    .map(word => word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1))
    .join(' ')

  const output = `
    <p>Thanks for shopping with us, ${nameCheck}.</p>
    <p>Your Total is $${total}</p>
    <hr />
    <p>Gabriel Pozo - React Cart Developer / Owner</p>
    <a href="https://reactshoppingcart1.herokuapp.com/">Shop</a>
  `

  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    port: 25,
    secure: false,
    auth: {
      user: 'beyondutraining@gmail.com', 
      pass
    },
    tls: { rejectUnauthorized: false }
  })

  const mailOptions = {
    from: '"Gabriel" <beyondutraining@gmail.com>',
    to: email,
    subject: 'Your Order',
    html: output
  }

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    error ? res.sendStatus(500) : res.sendStatus(200)
  })
})
```

This is how I'm serving static files from React:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('client/build'))

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'))
  })
}
```

This is how I'm assigning `env` variables:

```
module.exports = {
  PASS: process.env.PASS
}
```

If there's any other code you'd like, let me know!

Comment: Can you try logging the error the line before the ternary? That might provide a stack trace and description of what went wrong

Comment: @PatNeedham `null` is returned

Comment: What if you try something like `let statusCode = error ? 500 : 200` and then `res.sendStatus(statusCode)`.  It could be that even though `error` has a null value, the first case is still being evaluated.

Comment: Nope still get that error. I realized that when I write the code like so: `if (error) res.sendStatus(500) else res.sendStatus(200)` it hangs instead of failing right away so maybe it's something to do with how my `sendMail` function is written. Also if write it as so: `if (error) res.sendStatus(500) res.sendStatus(200)` it passes but doesn't send the email.

Comment: Did you get to solve this? I'm having the same problem. To see the error is throwing heroko write in the terminar addressing the project this code "heroku logs --source app".

Comment: @Angel Kind of. I switched my service to SendGrid and it works flawlessly. I suggest you give it a try!

Comment: @RogerFedFan I made it work, if you follow the steps in this link http://masashi-k.blogspot.com/2013/06/sending-mail-with-gmail-using-xoauth2.html you can do it too, let me know if you need a hand

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention whether you have set the environment variables on your Heroku project. It should be accessible at the link `https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/<your-project-id>/settings`. The `Config Vars` section has a `Reveal Config Vars` button - when pressed, you can add the key `PASS` and give it appropriate value.

Comment: Yes I have set them on my heroku dashboard